# No sound output or hardware to choose from in gnome sound settings

Tags: audio, debian, sound-card, alsa, debian-wheezy

There is no sound output when I try to play music or videos etc.

When I run

```
$ speaker-test
```

I get

```
speaker-test 1.0.25

Playback device is default Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1
channels Using 16 octaves of pink noise 
ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_card_driver returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
ALSA lib conf.c:4241:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory 
ALSA lib conf.c:4720:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory ALSA lib pcm.c:2217:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM
default Playback open error: -2,No such file or directory
```

`lspci` says my sound card is

```
00:11.5 Multimedia audio controller: VIA Technologies, Inc. VT8233/A/8235/8237 AC97 Audio Controller (rev 60)
```

Comment: What exact programs are you trying to use to play sound? What desktop environment are you using? Is `pulseaudio` running (try `ps -ef | grep pulseaudio`)? What files are in `/dev/snd` directory?

Comment: normally i use things like Banshee, Firefox or VLC to play audio, but nothing is working right now. I'm using Gnome 3.4.2.1 (classic mode). Pulseaudio is running. '/dev/snd' contains "seq" and "timer"

Comment: The `snd-via82xx` driver should have been loaded automatically. Any error messages in the system log when you unload and reload it?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: The absence of something like `/dev/snd/pcmc0d0p` suggests that the sound driver is not detecting your sound card properly. This is likely a bug in ALSA, or the support was removed because the hardware is so old (this latter part is unlikely, because ALSA generally doesn't remove hardware support). What kernel version are you running? Output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Also, follow Step 3 of this guide, except for the part where you post it on Launchpad. Just post the link it gives you when you run the command, to here. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: I'm currently running "i686 Linux 3.2.0-4-686-pae". here's the link it gave me: http://www.alsa-project.org/db/?f=cb200bb4973e8baf26ec8da9a8e25383b2c86afd